# Como fazer uma requisição GET em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em programação e estou fazendo alguns projetos e estudando para montar um portfolio. O meu problema atual está sendo com uma API de imagens (unsplash). Testei primeiro pelo insomnia fiz uma requisição GET para `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random`, lá forneci o Client-ID da API no header Authorization e recebi com sucesso um JSON com o link da imagem e outras informações. O meu gargalo está na hora de codar isso. Tentei usar o fetch como no código abaixo:

```js
    function setWallpaper() {
        fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random`).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            const { id } = data.id
            console.log(id);
        })
    }
```

Eu espero receber o ID da imagem, mas no console não aparece nada. Talvez seja porque falta colocar o Client-ID na header Authorization, mas não sei onde colocar essa informação no código.

Comment: Em `const { id } = data.id` na verdade você cria um objeto e joga fora. Tente `const id = data.id` e seu código deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente como é explicado na MDN:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Supplying_your_own_request_object
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers

Exemplo:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers({
    'Header-do-Client-ID': 'valor do header do Client-ID'
});

const myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders
};

const myRequest = new Request('https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random', myInit);

fetch(myRequest).then(response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    const { id } = data.id
    console.log(id);
});
```

Obviamente troque `Header-do-Client-ID` pelo nome do header correto e troque o `valor do header do Client-ID` também. Um exemplo se fosse com `bearer` (possivelmente):

```
const token = 'valor aqui';

const myHeaders = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
});

const myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders
};
```

Comment: Como posso saber se os valores foram retornados corretamente? O `console.log(id)` não é exibido no navegador, acho que não está pegando o json...

Comment: @DavidLima olha o console, veja se ocorreu algum erro.

Comment: @DavidLima tá entrando no then ou não?